# expected ';' before '{' token

Tags: c, libxml2

working in libxml and c, I have this code snippit:

```
if (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"headline")) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc,cur->xmlChildrenNode,1);
            conf_var.headline=key;
            xmlFree(key);
        } 
        elseif (!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"para")) {
            key = xmlNodeListGetString(doc,cur->xmlChildrenNode,1);
            conf_var.para=key;
            xmlFree(key);
        }
```

When I compile this, I get the following error:  things.c:29:59: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token

the line reffered is the elseif line.  I really don't know what is wrong here, as the same bit of code works just above it in the if command.  What's wrong here?

Answer (score 8):

There is no such thing as `elseif` in C.  It's `else if`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `elseif` in C, so the compiler thinks that it is an statement and waits for a terminator (`;`).

Use `else if`, instead.